# Silverlight create and execute file server-side

Tags: silverlight, kml

In my app i have the option of viewing a file that opens a window application (google earth).

In order to do that i wish to create a custom file server-side under a certain relative path (eg. "//Files") and then tell the server to execute it.

How can i do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You would need to expose the relative paths to your clients and then have them link to that location. How you set it up will depend heavily on what type of server we are talking about (Windows or Linux, IIS or Apache, etc).